# Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I get this error in my SwiftUI View, see code below; I also get Cannot convert return expression of type 'List' to return type 'some View'.

```
 struct RestaurantView: View {

    @State private var isSshowingMapActionSheet = false
    @State private var isShowingSafariView = false
    let restaurant: Restaurant!
    var currenstatus: String  {
        if restaurant.isOpen {
            return "Open"
        }
        return "Closed"
    }
    var mapActionSheetButtons: [ActionSheet.Button] = [
        .default("Open in Maps", action: {
            self.openInMaps()
        }),
        .default("Open in Google Maps", action: {
            self.openInGoogleMaps()
        }),
        .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
    ]
    lazy var mapActionSheet = ActionSheet(title: Text(""), buttons: mapActionSheetButtons)

    func openInMaps() {
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: restaurant.location.coordinate, addressDictionary: [CNPostalAddressStreetKey as String: restaurant.address!])

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = self.restaurant.name
        mapItem.phoneNumber = self.restaurant.phone

        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    func openInGoogleMaps() {
        if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/?q=\(restaurant.name.URLEncoded)@\(restaurant.location.coordinate.latitude),\(restaurant.location.coordinate.longitude)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }
    }



    var body: some View {
        List {
            ListRow("ClockGlyph", action: {

            }, label: {
                OpenHoursView(restaurant)
            })

        ListRow("PhoneGlyph", action: {
            UIApplication.shared.op
        }, label: {
            Text(self.restaurant!.phone)
        })

        if (restaurant.homepage != nil) {
            return ListRow("SafariGlyph", action: {
                isShowingSafariView.toggle()
            }, label:  {
                Text(restaurant.homepage)
            }
        }

        ListRow("PhoneGlyph", action: {
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(self.restaurant.phoneURL)
        }, label: {
            Text(self.restaurant.phone)
        })

            if restaurant!.facebookURL != nil {
                ListRow("FacebookGlyph", action: {
                }, label: {
                    Text(self.restaurant.facebookURL!)
                })
            }

        ListRow("PinGlyph", action: {
            self..isSshowingMapActionSheet.toggle()
        }, label: {
            VStack {
                Text(restaurant!.address!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ", "))
                Text("Visa vägbeskrivning")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }

        })

        .actionSheet(isPresented: $isSshowingMapActionSheet, content: {
                mapActionSheet
            })
        .sheet(item: $isShowingSafariView, content: {
                SafariView(url: restaurant.homepageURL)

            })
    }

}
```

And here's my `ListRow` class:

```
struct ListRow<Label> : View where Label : View {
    let image: Image
    var action:(() -> ())
    let label: () -> Label

    init(_ image: Image, action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.image = image
        self.action = action
        self.label = label
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                image.resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                self.label().font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: On the line with:
var body: some View

Answer (score 1):

There a few typos that cause the compiling to fail.

With SwiftUI you can get Xcode errors that are not very helpful, you should try commenting out different lines until it gives you are more informative error. With the new beta Xcode 11.4 it should be better.

In general, try building smaller views, break them out into separate structs more so that it's easier to spot typos, it will also help the compiler.

Comment: hank you for noticing the typo, but this is not what's causing the error.

Comment: @AndersFrohm could you provide a more complete code example

Comment: I also get Use of unresolved identifier 'self' on the lines  self.openInMaps() and self.openInGoogleMaps()